# Unpivoting for large dataset and greater number of unique columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The pivot and unpivot functions in snowflake are not efficient for processing 30+ unique columns into row based.

Use case : I have 35 different month columns which needs to be rows based , another 35 columns will be quantity for the corresponding month .
So at the and there will be 2 columns(one for month data and another for quantity) for 70 unique columns
there would be aggregation of quantity based on month
But unpivoting is not at all efficient. The below query is scanning 15 GB of data from the main table used

```
select part_num ,concat(date_part(year, dates),'-',date_part(month, dates)) as month_year,
sum(quantity) as quantities
 from table_name
unpivot(dates for cols in (month_1, 30 other uniue cols)),
unpivot(quantity for cols in (qunatity_1, 30 other uniue cols)),
group by part_num, month_year
```

Is there any other approach to unpivot large dataset.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach could be using conditional aggregation:

```
with cte as (
  select part_num
     ,concat(date_part(year, dates),'-',date_part(month, dates)) as month_year
     ,sum(quantity) as quantities
  from table_name
  group by part_num, month_year
)
SELECT part_num 
      -- lowest date
      ,'2020-01' AS "2020-01"
      ,MAX(IFF(month_year='2020-01', quantities, NULL) AS "quantities_2020-01"
      -- next date
      ,...
      -- last date
      ,'2022-04' AS "2022-04"
      ,MAX(IFF(month_year='2022-04', quantities, NULL) AS "quantities_2022-04"
FROM cte
GROUP BY part_num;
```

---

Version using single GROUP BY and `TO_VARCHAR` with format:

```
SELECT part_num 
  -- lowest date
  ,MAX(IFF(TO_VARCHAR(dates,'YYYY-MM'),'2020-01',NULL) AS "2020-01"
  ,MAX(IFF(TO_VARCHAR(dates,'YYYY-MM')='2020-01',quantities,NULL) AS "quantities_2020-01"
  -- next date
  ,...
  -- last date
  ,MAX(IFF(TO_VARCHAR(dates,'YYYY-MM'),'2022-04',NULL) AS "2022-04"
  ,MAX(IFF(TO_VARCHAR(dates,'YYYY-MM')='2022-04',quantities,NULL) AS "quantities_2022-04"
FROM table_name
GROUP BY part_num;
```

Comment: WE have data from many years, so it is not efficient running multiple max functions

Comment: @PriyaChauhan max is a very performant function. The bigger concern if you have so much data is ehy are yiu structuring/storing it how you dont need it. Verse how should/can you transform it.

Answer (score 1):

So if we get some example DATA and test is what is happening is what is wanted..

Here is a trival and tiny CTE worth of data

```
with table_name(part_num, month_1, month_2, month_3, qunatity_1, qunatity_2, qunatity_3) as (
    select * from values
    (1, '2022-01-01'::date, '2022-02-01'::date, '2022-03-01'::date, 4, 5, 6)
)
```

now pointing your SQL at it (after making it compile)

```
select 
   part_num
   ,to_char(dates, 'yyyy-mm') as month_year
   ,sum(quantity) as quantities
from table_name
    unpivot(dates for month in (month_1, month_2, month_3))
    unpivot(quantity for quan in (qunatity_1, qunatity_2, qunatity_3))
group by part_num, month_year
```

gives:

| PART_NUM | MONTH_YEAR | QUANTITIES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01 | 15 |
| 1 | 2022-02 | 15 |
| 1 | 2022-03 | 15 |

which is not what I think you are after.

If we look at the un aggregated rows:

| PART_NUM | MONTH | DATES | QUAN | QUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MONTH_1 | 2022-01-01 | QUNATITY_1 | 4 |
| 1 | MONTH_1 | 2022-01-01 | QUNATITY_2 | 5 |
| 1 | MONTH_1 | 2022-01-01 | QUNATITY_3 | 6 |
| 1 | MONTH_2 | 2022-02-01 | QUNATITY_1 | 4 |
| 1 | MONTH_2 | 2022-02-01 | QUNATITY_2 | 5 |
| 1 | MONTH_2 | 2022-02-01 | QUNATITY_3 | 6 |
| 1 | MONTH_3 | 2022-03-01 | QUNATITY_1 | 4 |
| 1 | MONTH_3 | 2022-03-01 | QUNATITY_2 | 5 |
| 1 | MONTH_3 | 2022-03-01 | QUNATITY_3 | 6 |

we are getting a cross join, which is not what I believe you are wanting.

my understanding is you want a relationship between month (1-35) and quantity (1-35)

thus a mix like:

| PART_NUM | MONTH | DATES | QUAN | QUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MONTH_1 | 2022-01-01 | QUNATITY_1 | 4 |
| 1 | MONTH_2 | 2022-02-01 | QUNATITY_2 | 5 |
| 1 | MONTH_3 | 2022-03-01 | QUNATITY_3 | 6 |

### Guessed Answer:

My guess at what you really are wanting is:

```
select
  part_num
  ,to_char(dates, 'yyyy-mm') as month_year
  ,array_construct(qunatity_1, qunatity_2, qunatity_3)[split_part(month,'_',2)::number - 1] as qunatity
from table_name
    unpivot(dates for month in (month_1, month_2, month_3))
order by 1,2;
```

which gives (for the same above CTE data):

| PART_NUM | MONTH_YEAR | QUNATITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01 | 4 |
| 1 | 2022-02 | 5 |
| 1 | 2022-03 | 6 |

Another way to way to get than guessed answer:

```
select
  part_num
  ,to_char(dates, 'yyyy-mm') as month_year
  ,sum(iff(split_part(month,'_',2)=split_part(q_name,'_',2), q_val, null)) as qunatity
from table_name
    unpivot(dates for month in (month_1, month_2, month_3))
    unpivot(q_val for q_name in (qunatity_1, qunatity_2, qunatity_3))
group by 1,2
order by 1,2;
```

which uses the double unpivot, so might be slow, but then only aggregates the values if they match. Which feels somewhat almost as gross as the build an array, to rip it apart, but that version is not needing to do large joins, just some per row grossness.

Comment: Bang on correct, you , your guessed answer worked. Thanks a ton Simeon. Next time, I will do the test on sample data to see the type of join it is doing.

Comment: @PriyaChauhan glad to here it was bang on... https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is already aggregated at `part_num` level, you could divide and conquer like this

```
with year_month as

(select a.part_num, b.index+1 as month_num, left(b.value,7) as year_month
 from my_table a,table(flatten(input=>array_construct(m1,m2,m3...))) b),

quantities as

(select a.part_num, b.index+1 as month_num, b.value::int as quantity
 from my_table a,table(flatten(input=>array_construct(q1,q2,q3...))) b)

select a.part_num, a.year_month, b.quantity
from year_month a
join quantities b on a.part_num=b.part_num and a.month_num=b.month_num
```